# How does chrome extend the search window beyond the browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, web

I just happened to notice the below behavior in chrome.The search suggestion is extending beyond the chrome window itself. I am curious as to how this can be implemented. Is this just some css styling? or something more?

[image: Google chrome]

Comment: What makes you think that that is a standard html element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This unfortunately is not possible. The search box is an internal part of chrome, thus part of the application itself. Your web page, which has the div inside of it is limited to the browser window itself, any attempt at breaking out of this container will simply end up in your div either being moved off-screen or your browser will simply get scrollbars. So long story short, this is not possible.

Besides that it would be quite dangerous as malicious users could pretty much take over everything you see on your computer screen.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Paradoxis his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29447436/3571997) but there is a way. I can't see any use in it but a select box with a lot of options can extend beyond the chrome window.

[image: Chrome]

I have tried playing with the width and height of the select box to, but as expected that only applies for within the window.

Comment: But you can't really do much with it tough ;)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you see in the screenshot is the ellipsis property of css
http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/kaJ3L/1/

Still if you want to extend some div beyond the window of your browser
then try giving it more width than the width of your browser
eg:

```
width: 1900px;
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you misunderstood his question, its about the suggested pages going below the actual chrome application.